# Search in Fluent-NHibernate using session.QueryOver<> return empty

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Hey everyone I am new to ORM, Im using Fluent NHibernate in my CRUD seems to have a problem in my search, it will return an empty or null value and also I can insert data, but when i insert another record its seems updating bcoz it replace my previous record. I try doing some google but still no used. Can anyone give me some tutorial links.

My Code:

employee Class in objclass folder

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace fluent.objclass
  {
     public class employees
     {
        public virtual int employee_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string employee_code { get; set; }
        public virtual string last_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string first_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string middle_initial { get; set; }
        ect..
     }
  }
```

My Mapping Class in map class folder

```
  using fluent.objclass;
  using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace fluent.mapclass
 {
 public class employeesMap: ClassMap<employees>
 {
    public employeesMap() 
    {
        Id(x => x.employee_id);
        Map(x => x.employee_code);
        Map(x => x.last_name);
        Map(x => x.first_name);
        Map(x => x.middle_initial);
        ect..
      }
   }
 }
```

My Repository in repository folder

```
using fluent.objclass;
using NHibernate;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace fluent.repository
{
public class emp_repository
{
    public void INSERT(employees newEmp) 
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()) 
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) 
            {
                session.Save(newEmp);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

    }

    public employees GetemployeesbyLName(int input) 
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()) 
        {
            var result = session.QueryOver<employees>().Where(x =>  x.employee_id == input).SingleOrDefault();
            return result ?? new employees(); 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My NHibernateHelper

```
using fluent.objclass;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace fluent
 {
   public class NHibernateHelper
  {
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {

        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                InitializeSessionFactory();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                         .ConnectionString(@"Server=ARK\DARKAGE;Database=PNH;Trusted_Connection=True;")
                        .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                            .AddFromAssemblyOf<employees>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                    .Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
      }

      public static ISession OpenSession()
      {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();

      }
  }

}
```

my code snipe

```
   using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
   using fluent.objclass;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using NHibernate.Linq;
   using fluent.repository;

   namespace fluent
   {
      public partial class fluent : Form
      {
         emp_repository repo = new emp_repository();
         public fluent()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void bntADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                var emp = new employees
                {
                    employee_code = txtBAR.Text.Trim(' '),
                    last_name = txtLNM.Text.Trim(' '),
                    first_name = txtFNM.Text.Trim(' '),
                    middle_initial = txtMNM.Text.Trim(' '),
                    ect...
                };
                repo.INSERT(emp);
                MessageBox.Show(txtLNM.Text.Trim(' ') + "Successfully Added To Record");
    }

      private void bntSE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        employees emp = repo.GetemployeesbyLName(1);
        MessageBox.Show(emp.last_name);
      }

    }
  }
```

Finally my Table

```
 USE [PNH]
 GO
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees](
[employee_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[employee_code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[last_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[first_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[middle_initial] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
ect...
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [employee_id] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO
```

:( sorry for my poor english and alignment :( Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first sight, I actually noticed two possible problems with your code.

**First:**

Have you tried to profile your generated SQL? With a profler tool like [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof).

**Edit:**

Another option for logging could be, if you extend the `FluentConfiguration` setup by adding:

```
.Diagnostics(d => d.Enable(true))
.Diagnostics(d => d.OutputToConsole())
```

Where as the first line enables conditional logging, the second line sets diagnostic logging to console.

So then you could really see what is going on in the background, as i doubt its actually replacing your existing record.

Since you are calling the `Save()` method which

> Persists the given transient instance

However you are stating that it gets "replaced", which would be equivalent to call `SaveOrUpdate()` method which

> Either Save() or Update() the given instance, depending upon the value
>   of its identifier property.

**Second:**

Do you need to create the whole database schema each time you instantiate your `NHibernate` helper?

Because you are calling the `ExposeConfiguration()` method with `SchemaExport.Create(true, true)`.

Where `SchemaExport.Create(...)`

> Runs the schema creation script

By passing the second boolean parameter to `Create()`, you are actually telling to execute the creation of the schema.

In short this means it will drop and re-create tables on every run.

So if you are connecting to already existing schema, you could comment out the `SchemaExport` call, unless you are using this for example in-memory sql server.

Hope it helps!

P.s.: quotes taken from Fluent Nhibernates XMLdoc signatures.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my post and thank you for the suggestion ya I miss that part ExposeConfiguration() method every time I execute it will drop and recreate the tables. Thats why i change it to            .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))

Comment: Actually I already solve my problem a while ago and post my answer here. below is my edited NHibernateHelper, but I havent try the NHProf or logging. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

My Error is in NHibernateHelper.cs in

```
     ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true);
```

Every I run and execute it will drop the current table and recreate thats why my search returns empty and my add replaces every time I add a new entries

my Correct NHibernateHelper.cs

```
 using fluent.objclass;
 using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
 using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
 using NHibernate;
 using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace fluent
   {
   public class NHibernateHelper
   {
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static readonly object factorylock = new object();
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {

        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                InitializeSessionFactory();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }
    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                        .ConnectionString(@"Server=ARK\DARKAGE;Database=PNH;Trusted_Connection=True;").ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                            .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
                return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
  }

}
```